# How to setup programmatically the background color of a marketing cloud Layout block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketingcloudapi

I am struggling with the possiblity of configuring programmatically the background color of a Layout Block that I have in Email Studio.

I don't find the possibility of doing that using AMPSCript. It should be possible to do that accessing and updating the block via Content Builder API calls ? Any example of that ?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Enrique

Comment: Very similar to what you’re asking:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272074/global-template-background-and-content-background

Comment: Hey Enrique, how will the BG colours be determined? Is there a colour code stored within the sendable DE, or will you be assigning colours based on other values/on send? How many colours options are there?

Comment: Hi Cameron, colours are stored in a DE. Any kind of colour can be setup. Thanks for your help !